# Knowing which button was clicked in Android

Tags: java, android, android-button

I am making an app which will contain 81 buttons on the same layout. They are all referred as an object I created called "Tile". Problem is those tiles are stored in an array, so I need to know which button was clicked in an int format to be able to call a tile ( `tiles[??]` ). I am using an `onClick(View v)` method. Also I have tried this:

```
Log.i("Tile", v.getId() + "was clicked")
```

The result it gave me in the logcat was a really long integer.

So how can I know which button was clicked in a number format? And what is the relationship between the casual id (`R.id.tile1`) and this long integer, as it could help because it is already a number?

PS: I know I could use Switch to assign each id to an integer, but as they are 81, it will be a waste of time and will make the code very complicated.

Comment: why don't you use postion to determine which button click?

Comment: I didn't understand, can you give more details please. Thanks ;)

Comment: you are using click listener like: tiles[i].setOnClickListener(this); right?

Comment: i think you should use GridView with Button Custom layout. by which you can easily get the position of which button is Clicked....by the way if you comfortable with button then you have to make a switch Condition in onClick() of button and compare like v.getId()==R.id.tile1, it will give you exact value as id of which button you clicked.

Comment: @PhilippeSarouphim simple solution in your xml file set "android:tag=1"..and so on upto 81 for all buttons. Now implement OnClickListerner. Inside OnClickListener write view.getTag() which return your button number now you can easily perform your operation.

Comment: `v.getId()` gives the same id which you gave in xml file for that view during click event.

Comment: @NitinPatel yes but in the logcat, instead of returning a value similar to R.id... , it returned a weird integer of approximately > 2000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you can use tag option. You can set the tag for a view by view.setTag(1) and then on click event you can get back the tag set using view.getTag().

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to find view by tag?

Comment: Yes its working right. But, just like we refer to an object by its id, is there a way to refer to it by it's tag?

Answer (score 0):

In android we can use the id of the button for getting the click event in on click listener. 
Say you have, 5 Buttons:
Make sure your Activity/Fragment implement OnClickListener

// in OnCreate

```
  Button mClickButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton1);
  mClickButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
  Button mClickButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton2);
  mClickButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
  Button mClickButton3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton3);
  mClickButton3.setOnClickListener(this);
  Button mClickButton4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton4);
  mClickButton4.setOnClickListener(this);
  Button mClickButton5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton5);
  mClickButton5.setOnClickListener(this);</br>
```

//after this you will override the onclick method from OnClickListener

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {
      case  R.id.clickButton1: {
        // do something for button 1 click
        break;
      }
      case R.id.clickButton2: {
        // do something for button 2 click
        break;
      }

    //.... etc
   }
}
```

Comment: This involves writing a `switch` which contains 81 cases

Comment: Yes,If you have 81 button then you have to write 81 cases for that.

Comment: The whole question's purpose is to find a way to avoid 81 repetitions.

Comment: So you have to put all the button in a parent-layout and get the child-id on click of button without using the switch case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use button.setTag(position) to set position as tag.

And when onclick called get that tag value.

```
public void onclick(View v){
  int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
 }
```